# Alcatel pop c1 soft bricked

Tags: unbricking

Hello guys I have a problem with my Alcatel pop c1 which is soft bricked stuck on a boot logo I can only boot in stock recovery I don't have twrp or any custom recovery and no access to a PC for the moment 
Can I flash any rom with "apply update from SD card " i think I lost my system folder and I got no backup
I'm in a real mess please inform me if there's anything I can do
I have downloaded the stock rom but it says installation aborted

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `Mobile Upgrade` software listed on their support page?

http://www.alcatel-mobile.com/global-en/support/product?id=330&model=POP%20C1

Comment: I said I don't have access to a PC

Comment: My bad, I missed that. Try using a friend's PC as doing it on the phone itself can be needlessly difficult. P.S. I know this after having flashed multiple devices many times.

Comment: It recognises it but only as adb sideload what can I do ??!